# What does it mean when the author says two variables grow at the same rate along the steady-state path?

Tags: macroeconomics, solow

I was studying the Solow model of growth. If $k_t$ denotes the capita-labor ratio and $y_t$ denotes the output-labor ratio, what does the following statement mean along the steady-state growth path:

> $\frac{k_{t+1}}{k_t}$ and $\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_t}$ grow at  the same rate

If $\frac{k^s_{t+1}}{k^s_t} = c_1$ and $\frac{y^s_{t+1}}{y^s_t} = c_2$ where $c_1 \neq c_2$ are both constants, can we still say that they grow at the same rate since neither grows at all? Or does the statement imply that, along the steady-state path (hence, a tiny $^s$ on top the variables), $\frac{k^s_{t+1}}{k^s_t} = \frac{y^s_{t+1}}{y^s_t}$?

What I think is that if $\frac{d \left(\frac{k^s_{t+1}}{k^s_t}\right)}{dt} = \frac{d \left(\frac{y^s_{t+1}}{y^s_t}\right)}{dt}$ holds, then they grow at the same rate.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: "*If $\frac{k^s_{t+1}}{k^s_t} = c_1$ and $\frac{y^s_{t+1}}{y^s_t} = c_2$ where $c_1 \neq c_2$ are both constants, can we still say that they grow at the same rate since neither grows at all?*" Why do you write that these $k,y$ values do not grow? That would only be true if the $c$ values were both equal to 1?

Comment: @Giskard $k$, $y$ values grow, but the $\frac{k_{t+1}}{k_t}$ (similarly, $y$) values do not (I think). I am not exactly sure whose growth the author is referring - the ratio or the individual variables $k,y$, albeit I think it's the former.

Comment: Okay, I understand your question now. Without providing an exact reference for your quote, it is probably impossible to answer this.